# Mock a service while running a BrowserTest?

Tags: 8, testing

I am trying to test the output of a controller that returns some information in a given page. This controller has a custom http client injected into it.

I want to create a BrowserTest that can navigate to a fake node, and then test for certain text or values. I also want to change the mock to return different values, so I can further test the output to account for those cases.

I tried:

```
    $client = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\mymodule\Client\AuthorizeClient')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $client->expects($this->any())
      ->method('request')
      ->with('w12345', FALSE)
      ->willReturn([]);

    $this->container->set('mymodule.auth_client', $client);
```

But I get errors in the test that refer to the original class, and not the one I am trying to replace. I looked around in the core but wasn't really able to find what I was looking for. Does it make sense to do this? Is there a way to do a Kernel test to test responses from the route in question?

Answer (score 1):

I could not quite get my mocked service to be used from the container as per the docs, so I resulted to doing this.

I don't really need a BrowserTest per se, as I just want to ensure the Response object contains what it should. I create a client mock and instantiate the controller object myself:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\mymodule\Kernel;

use Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase;
use Drupal\mymodule\Controller\AuthorizeController;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem;

/**
 * Tests the AuthorizeController controller.
 *
 * @group mymodule
 */
class AuthorizeControllerTest extends KernelTestBase {

  /**
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['system', 'node', 'field', 'mymodule', 'file', 'mymodule_authtest', 'user', 'text'];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->installConfig(['node', 'user', 'mymodule_authtest', 'file']);
    $this->installSchema('file', ['file_usage']);
    $this->installEntitySchema('user');
    $this->installEntitySchema('node');
    $this->installEntitySchema('file');

    $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule_authtest');

    $uri = $this->container->get('file_system')->copy("$module_path/fixtures/pdf/foo.pdf", 'public://foo.pdf', FileSystem::EXISTS_REPLACE);

    $file = File::Create([
      'uri' => $uri,
    ]);
    $file->save();

    $node = Node::create(array(
      'title' => t('Test Paper'),
      'type' => 'working_paper',
      'language' => 'en',
      'field_id' => 'w12345',
      'field_paper_working_paper' => $file->id(),
    ));
    $node->save();
  }

  /**
   * Test different scenarios and responses from our controller.
   */
  public function testControllerResponse() {
    $node = $this->container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node')->load(1);

    $client = $this->getMockClient(1, 3, 3);
    $controller = $this->getAuthorizeController($client);
    $response = $controller->content($node);
    $this->assertContains('You’ve used 3 of your 3 allowed downloads for the year.', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertContains('Download Paper Anyway', $response->getContent());

    $client = $this->getMockClient(1, 3, 1);
    $controller = $this->getAuthorizeController($client);
    $response = $controller->content($node);
    $this->assertContains('You’ve used 1 of your 3 allowed downloads for the year.', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertContains('Download Paper Anyway', $response->getContent());

    $client = $this->getMockClient(1, 2, 1);
    $controller = $this->getAuthorizeController($client);
    $response = $controller->content($node);
    $this->assertContains('You’ve used 1 of your 2 allowed downloads for the year.', $response->getContent());

    $client = $this->getMockClient(0, 3, 3);
    $controller = $this->getAuthorizeController($client);
    $response = $controller->content($node);
    $this->assertNotContains('Download Paper Anyway', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertContains('<a href="http://example.org?id=w12345" class="btn btn--primary btn--black">Purchase Paper for $5</a>', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertContains('<a href="http://example.org?referer=http%3A//localhost/node/1" class="btn btn--primary btn--black">Have Access? Login to Account</a>', $response->getContent());
  }

  /**
   * Return a mocked client. Allow changing of some values to influence the
   * controllers response object.
   */
  protected function getMockClient(int $allow = 1, int $claims_max = 3, int $claims_used = 1) {
    $client = $this->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\mymodule\Client\AuthorizeClient')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $client->expects($this->any())
      ->method('request')
      ->with('w12345', FALSE)
      ->willReturn(
        [
          'allow' => $allow,
          'claims_max' => $claims_max,
          'claims_used' => $claims_used,
          'failed_reason' => NULL,
          'succeeded_reason' => NULL,
          'subscriber_id' => 12345,
          'subscriber_logo_url' => NULL,
          'subscriber_name' => "Test",
          'subscriber_type' => "SUBS",
        ]
      );

    return $client;
  }

  /**
   * Return a controller with a mocked client.
   */
  protected function getAuthorizeController($client) {
    return new AuthorizeController($client, $this->container->get('renderer'), $this->container->get('entity_type.manager'), $this->container->get('request_stack'), $this->container->get('logger.factory'));
  }

}
```

This seems like a valid approach and the cases are working, and executes much faster than browser tests. The `mymodule_authtest` contains a content type with a couple of field configuration files and example PDF file to use in this test.