# How do I mock a service when using BroswerTestBase?

Tags: 8, testing, dependency-injection

I am trying to use BrowserTestBase to write a functional test for a Form. The form populates some form elements with data retrieved from an external site. The client for this external site is injected into the form as a Drupal 8 service. The client uses Guzzle, and I'm building the mock client using code similar to the following one.

```php
$myClient = new MyClient(Drupal::configFactory(), [
  'handler' => HandlerStack::create(
    new MockHandler([
      new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], 'Hello, World')
    ])
  ),
  'base_uri' => 'http://example.com/api/',
]);
```

I've tried doing this in the test class to assign my mock client to the service.

```php
$this->container->set('my.service', $mockClient);
```

I've tried placing this assignment in `setUp()` as well as the `testMyForm()` method itself, but the container passed to the form's `create()` method doesn't contain `$mockClient`.

**Update:**

After digging into the code I discovered that parameters and services may be initialized in the test-site context by adding them inside `testing.services.yml` and placing that in the default site folder. In my test I used:

```
services:
  browser_test.handler_stack:
    class: GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack
    factory: GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create
    arguments:
      - '@browser_test.mock_handler'
  browser_test.mock_handler:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler
  my.service:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Client\MyClient
    arguments:
      - '@config.factory'
      -
        base_uri: 'http://localhost/test/'
        handler: '@browser_test.handler_stack'
```

This overrode the client (which solves part of the problem), however I'm still unable to inject mock responses into `MockHandler` from the test class. I tried:

```php
/** @var MockHandler $handlerStack */
$handler = $this->container->get('browser_test.mock_handler');
$handler->append(new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], 'Hello, World'));

$this->drupalLogin($this->adminUser);
$this->drupalGet('path/to/my_form');
$this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals(200);
```

But MockHandler is throwing an exception because `Mock queue is empty`.

Comment: I also was trying this earlier in the week. The docs state that this is how you'd override it, but I was not seeing that to be the case. Interested in any answers.

Comment: For reference... https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/289129/mock-a-service-while-running-a-browsertest

Comment: It looks like params and services can be initialized by adding a `sites/default/testing.services.yml` file to the site. This file gets copied to the site provisioned for the functional test (see [FunctionalTestSetupTrait::prepareSettings()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Test%21FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php/function/FunctionalTestSetupTrait%3A%3AprepareSettings/8.8.x). However it's still unclear if it's possible to inject mock responses to Guzzle requests from the Test class to the test site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock a service while running a BrowserTest?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/289129/mock-a-service-while-running-a-browsertest)

Comment: I it is not possible to modify the guzzle options after the guzzle client has been initiated. This isn't necessarily a duplicate, but I think overriding the _output_ of the service's method like @leymannx suggests is appropriate rather than try to test the internals of Guzzle.